# Symfony 4: Embed form child Create New On Update

Tags: forms, logic, symfony4

This is what I've done so far:
I have a Patient(parent entity) and a File(child entity) each Patient is created with two files when the patient is edited I could edit the two files.

What's needed :

Instead of editing the same files I want that each time The patient is updated the form gets populated with the latest (based on the creation date) files but when submitting it should create new files and keep the old ones in the database

Could someone give me some suggestions and references?
Thanks

```php
//Patient controller Edit Function

public function edit(Request $request, Patient $patient): Response
    {        
        $types=$this->getListData('types');
        $form = $this->createForm(PatientType::class, $patient,array(
            'types'             => $types,
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('patient_show', [
                'id' => $patient->getId(),
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render($brand.'/edit.html.twig', [
            'patient' => $patient,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);     
    }
```

Comment: The loggable doctrine extension from https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions does this but at the entity level instead of the controller.

Comment: So basically you want immutable `File` objects and replace them with new instances instead of editing?

Comment: yes but without deleting the old File objects